# Django AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS check for symbols and other requirements

Tags: python, django, web-applications, passwords

Is it possible to validate password requirements such as:

- One capital letter
- Two symbols

using Django's inbuilt password management? e.g. these:

```
django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator
django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator
django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator
django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator
```

I found the following Python package that does what I'd like but I'm wondering if it can be done natively:

https://pypi.org/project/django-password-validators/

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You can [write your own validator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/passwords/#writing-your-own-validator)
Django’s password validators have a fairly small interface. They must implement two methods:

`validate(self, password, user=None)` Must return None if the password is valid, or raise a ValidationError with an error message if the password is not valid. You must be able to deal with the user being None - if that means your validator can’t run, return None for no error. In most cases, you wouldn't even need the user to validate the password (it's more for cases where we want to prevent password reuse)
`get_help_text()` Must provide some help text to explain the password requirements to the user.

Any items in the `OPTIONS` in `AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS` for your validator will be passed to the constructor. All constructor arguments should have a default value.

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _

class CaptialAndSymbolValidator:
    def __init__(self, number_of_capitals=1, number_of_symbols=2, symbols="[~!@#$%^&*()_+{}\":;'[]"):
        self.number_of_capitals = number_of_capitals
        self.number_of_symbols = number_of_symbols
        self.symbols = symbols

    def validate(self, password, user=None):
        capitals = [char for char in password if char.isupper()]
        symbols = [char for char in password if char in self.symbols]
        if len(capitals) < self.number_of_capitals:
            raise ValidationError(
                _("This password must contain at least %(min_length)d capital letters."),
                code='password_too_short',
                params={'min_length': self.number_of_capitals},
            )
        if len(symbols) < self.number_of_symbols:
            raise ValidationError(
                _("This password must contain at least %(min_length)d symbols."),
                code='password_too_short',
                params={'min_length': self.number_of_symbols},
            )

    def get_help_text(self):
        return _(
            "Your password must contain at least %(number_of_capitals)d capital letters and %(number_of_symbols) symbols."
            % {'number_of_capitals': self.number_of_capitals, 'number_of_symbols': self.number_of_symbols}
        )


AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    ...
    {
    'NAME': 'path.to.your.validators.CaptialAndSymbolValidator',
    'OPTIONS': {
        # use this to override any of the defaults
        'symbols': "@^#",
        }
    },
]
```

Comment: Thank you, just implemented this. I'm not too sure what the path is though, if it's located in main/testing/validators/validate.py would that be main.testing.validators.validate.CapitalAndSymbolValidator?

Comment: yes, that is correct (assuming main is the folder where your `manage.py` file is)

Comment: @andredms consider validating this answer as the current one. It worked for me. Thanks Resley Rodrigues